# Inverting high DC voltages

Tags: voltage, power

How do I turn a high negative DC voltage into a positive DC voltage around -88v?

I need to do this to be able to measure this across a sense resistor using an LTC2992

Comment: Why not attenuate by voltage divider and invert? Since you will know the total attenuation you will know the true negative voltage.

Comment: Indeed, though it would be preferable to start with a smaller sense resistor.  If your issue is a small voltage range with a large offset you should explain so and give the whole circuit as that is a very different problem.

Comment: I wanted to make a circuit which is able to test a power supply which I built. I was going to do this by using a mostfet as a voltage controlled resistor and have a sense resistor connected to the drain pin. The power supply has a negative rail which was the problem but its now been solved so I am happy about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to do this to be able to measure this across a sense resistor
>   using an LTC2992

The [LTC2992](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc2992.pdf) will handle negative power rails: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks this will be helpful